# How to restore full localhost.sql

Tags: mysql

So I wanted to format my system and I had a lot of works that I have done on my localhost that involves databases. 
I followed the normal way of backing up the database by exporting it into an SQL file but I think I made a mess by making a mistake of backing up everything in one SQL file (I mean the whole localhost was exported to just one SQL file).

The problem now is: when I try to import the backed up file I mean the (localhost.sql), I get an error like  #1046 No database has been selected

Comment: How are you restoring the sql file, does it include schema ?

Comment: In CLI execute `CREATE DATABASE databasename; USE databasename` then execute `SOURCE 'X:\folder_tree\localhost.sql'`.